# Supercollider as a midi patchbay

Tags: macos, midi, supercollider

How could I use Supercollider (3.3) as a midi patchbay 

I get the sources and destinations 

    `MIDIClient.init;` 
    `MIDIEndPoint("USB Axiom 25", "Anschluss 1")` 

and connect one source. 

    `MIDIIn.connect(device: 3);` 

I take a destination, give it a variable 

    `m = MIDIOut.newByName("FluidSynth virtual port (28209)", "FluidSynth virtual   port (28209)");`


and send midi events by click. 

    `m.noteOn(1, 60, 60);`
    `m.noteOff(1, 60, 60);`

But how to send from the source direct to the destination through supercollider?